# With a samlWebSso20 config on WebSphere Liberty and an ADFS server, what is the proper way to define security roles / contraints

Tags: ibm-cloud, saml-2.0, websphere-liberty, adfs3.0

I have put in place a `samlWebSso20` config using the `Liberty Buildpack` on Bluemix and the `ADFS idp` from my customer.

I have a single web application deployed on the Liberty instance.

I am using the `Server Directory` option to push on Bluemix as explained [here](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/runtimes/liberty/optionsForPushing.html)

Here is my *server.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<server description="johan">
<featureManager>
    <feature>webProfile-7.0</feature>
    <feature>samlWeb-2.0</feature>
    <feature>appSecurity-2.0</feature>
</featureManager>

<samlWebSso20 id="defaultSP" nameIDFormat="unspecified"
    spCookieName="my_cookie"
    idpMetadata="${server.config.dir}/resources/security/FederationMetadata.xml"
    userIdentifier="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn"
    sessionNotOnOrAfter="2h">
</samlWebSso20>

<keyStore id="defaultKeyStore" password="***" />

<webApplication context-root="/" location="MySampleApp.war" name="MySampleApp" type="war">
    <security-role name="any-authenticated">
        <special-subject type="ALL_AUTHENTICATED_USERS" />
    </security-role>

    <security-role name="administrators">
        <user name="user1@customer.com" />
        <user name="user2@customer.com" />
    </security-role>
</webApplication>
```

And here is the *web.xml* of the app deployed on Liberty

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>SampleAppServicesConstraint</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>SampleAppServices</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>PUT</http-method>
        <http-method>HEAD</http-method>
        <http-method>TRACE</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
        <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
        <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>any-authenticated</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>SampleAppAdminConstraint</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>SampleAppAdmin</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/admin</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>administrators</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<display-name>SampleApp</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

When I hit the /admin route of the SampleApp, I get redirected to the ADFS login page. I then log in with user1@customer.com and get redirected to my app. However, I get a 403 even though the user is in the 'administrators' role.
Below is the error message in the logs:

```
[AUDIT ] CWWKS9104A: Authorization failed for user user1@customer.com while invoking MySampleApp on /admin. The user is not granted access to any of the required roles: [administrators].
```

Note that if I change the AuthConstraint role from `administrators` to `any_authenticated` for the /admin route, user1@customer.com can then access the admin page.

Could someone please share some experience and explain what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
<security-role name="administrators">
    <user name="user1@customer.com" />
    <user name="user2@customer.com" />
</security-role>
```

To

```
<security-role name="administrators">
        <user name="user1@customer.com" access-id="user:<issuer name here> /user1@customer.com"/>
        <user name="user2@customer.com" access-id="user:<issuer name here> /user1@customer.com"/>
</security-role>
```

where  is the issuer name as appeared in SAML.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you very much